# How do I build cabal sandbox build src that depends on a lib which itself depends on a patched lib?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to using cabal sandbox to build a source file that depends on a library which itself depends on a patched library. However, based on error messages, it appears that cabal install --dependencies-only is not using the patched library. This is the command sequence I am using

```
cabal init sandbox
cabal sandbox add-source patchedsublib
cabal sandbox add-source lib
cabal install --only-dependencies
```

Building the library separately (with patchedsublib) works correctly.

Comment: Have you checked that lib's version constraint allow it to use patchedsublib?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to clarify that I can build lib+patchedsublib (in fact lib fails to build without using patchedsublib). My problem is building myexec+lib+patchedsublib.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you [file a ticket on the Cabal bug tracker](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/new)?

Comment: More likely I am doing something wrong. Am I supposed to be using shared sandboxes in this scenario?

Comment: Shared sandbox might work, but I agree with @MikhailGlushenkov that it is likely a bug as secondary dependency is not resolved within the sandbox.

Comment: Is there a work around?

Comment: As a workaround, I used shared sandbox, and built the tertiary dependency first (without doing add-source). Another way might be to update cabal to include tertiary library.